# ImageResizer and sharpening

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer

What about sharpen a picture? I didn't find a way to sharpen a picture after resizing it. When I resize a large picture, it seems to be a bit blurry. At least my customers want to have a more "crispy" look.

Answer (score 0):

#### With the [AdvancedFilters plugin installed](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/advancedfilters), you can apply an unsharp mask with `&a.sharpen=radius`.

By default a Bicubic Smoother resampling filter is applied, as this gives the best results for nearly all photographs.